# Foreign key widget finds more than 1 value, how should i approach this

Tags: django, django-models, django-import-export

I am using django-import-export library and I am trying to implement ForeignKey widget which is available to lookup related objects using Author.name instead of Author.pk. Now, the here is the tricky part for the given calendar year I only have one author with the same name, however, next year the author name will be similar. When i try to import, of course, it brings the issue saying that more than Author.name was found.

Is there a suggestion to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've used [`before_save_instance()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.before_save_instance) to do something similar to this. Here's some pseudo-code for how this might work:

```
class MyModelResource(ModelResource):
    # Specify fields and Meta information here
    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        # Replace the below with your actual code
        year = instance.year
        author = Author.objects.filter(year=year)
        instance.author = author
        return instance
```

This assumes that the information you need to get the correct author is available in the row you're importing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! So how do I pass the year? Should I create another row and delete it in the before_save_instance?

Comment: @bisamov That depends on your particular situation, but whatever logic you need to do you can do it in `before_save_instance()`. If you know that the year is always going to be the current year, for example, you wouldn't have to have a separate year column and you could just filter on `datetime.now().year`.

Comment: I am trying to implement that but can't get it right. Do you by any chance have a resource I could take a look?

Comment: Can the  class FullNameForeignKeyWidget(ForeignKeyWidget): be used to limit the query for particular year?